# Is $p(y_i|\pi)$ a common notation of discrete probability distribution?

Tags: probability, notation

Section 3.5 of ["Kevin Patrick Murphy. Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective."](http://noiselab.ucsd.edu/ECE228/Murphy_Machine_Learning.pdf) uses
$p(y_i|\pi)$ to denote the prior distribution in Bayes rule.

I've seen this kind of notation $Pr(y_i)$ a lot, to denote a discrete probability distribution, and rarely saw $p(y_i|\pi)$.

So, is $p(y_i|\pi)$ a common notation of discrete probability distribution

Comment: It is an abuse of notation, but common, yes.

Comment: @Math1000  Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I will let someone else do that. I am not certain enough of the proper notation to write an answer to this question.